# ng-change is watching for all items in ng-repeat instead of one item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this template:

```
<div class=characteristics-list>
    <input ng-model="search" ng-change="onSearchChange(search)">
    <div ng-repeat="policy in item.policies" ng-include="'policy.html'"></div>
</div>
```

and this logic inside controller:

```
$scope.onSearchChange = function (originalValue) {
    var value = originalValue.toLowerCase();

    if (!value) {
        $scope.item.policies.forEach(function (policy) {
            policy.isCollapsed = true;
            policy.isHidden = false;
            policy.items.forEach(function (item) {
                item.isHidden = false;
            });
        });
        return;
    }

    $scope.item.policies.forEach(function (policy) {
        var isValueInPolicyName = policy.name.toLowerCase().includes(value);

        var visibleItems = policy.items.filter(function (item) {
            var isValueInDescription = item.description.toLowerCase().includes(value);

            item.isHidden = !isValueInDescription;
            return isValueInDescription;
        });

        policy.isHidden = !isValueInPolicyName && !visibleItems.length;

        if (!isValueInPolicyName && !!visibleItems.length) {
            policy.isCollapsed = false;
        }

        if (isValueInPolicyName && !visibleItems.length) {
            policy.items.forEach(function (item) {
                item.isHidden = false;
            });
        }
    });
};
```

The result of changing search value is presented on the picture attached.

[image]

When input value is changed, the function is firing, but it's searching in each item inside ng-repeat. How do I handle just one current item without affecting all other items in ng-repeat?
It means, when I change the search value in one item, it should not handle other items.
I tried to create unique ng-models dynamically, but it doesn't help.
AngularJS version is 1.2.27

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What is your code supposed to do? Can you provide the code in policy.html ?

Comment: Also your title is misleading : ng-change is not watching for all items. Your `onSearchChange` function is looping through your `$scope.item.policies` array.

Comment: As @GuillaumeGeorges has stated, it's not `ng-change` doing anything here.  `ng-change` is responding to the change in the `search` input element, and calling `onSearchChange`.  it's your `onSearchChange` function that is looping through the entire array.  It's not really clear what you would expect it to do instead;  you say "handle just one current item", but what item would that be?

Comment: it's hard to tell what your issue is from the screenshot you posted, because the input box you are changing **is not** the search input that you posted code for. That *appears to be* in the policy.html code.  Instead of posting screenshots, you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: looking again, it actually seems like maybe the code you did post is wrapped inside **a different** `ng-repeat`. it's still hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish from the pieces you've provided so far.